# Failed to build Distribution.Simple package using stack in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

the stack command  `stack new my-project` creates a auto-generated file *Setup.hs* with contents:

```
import Distribution.Simple 
main = defaultMain
```

but my vs code intellisense just tells me

> Could not load module ‘Distribution.Simple’
> It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-3.2.1.0’.
> You can run ‘:set -package Cabal’ to expose it.
> (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)

so I tried to install the distribution package via command

`stack install distribution`

However I got the following message:

```
WARNING: Ignoring distribution's bounds on containers (==0.5.*); using containers-0.6.5.1.
Reason: allow-newer enabled.
WARNING: Ignoring distribution's bounds on random (==1.1.*); using random-1.2.0.
Reason: allow-newer enabled.
distribution> configure
distribution> Configuring distribution-1.1.1.0...
distribution> build
distribution> Preprocessing library for distribution-1.1.1.0..
distribution> Building library for distribution-1.1.1.0..
distribution> [1 of 8] Compiling Data.Distribution.Core
distribution> 
distribution> Data\Distribution\Core.hs:173:10: error:
distribution>     • Could not deduce (Semigroup (Distribution a))
distribution>         arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
distribution>       from the context: (Ord a, Monoid a)
distribution>         bound by the instance declaration
distribution>         at Data\Distribution\Core.hs:173:10-53
distribution>     • In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Distribution a)’
distribution>     |
distribution> 173 | instance (Ord a, Monoid a) => Monoid (Distribution a) where
distribution>     |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
distribution> 

--  While building package distribution-1.1.1.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\274b403a build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you have that package installed, but it is not listed as a dependency in your project. You need to add it in the `package.yaml` in `library/dependencies` or your exe:

```
library:
  source-dirs: src
  dependencies:
    - Cabal
```

(also note that the package you miss is `Cabal` as stated in the message, not `distribution` which is just a module name)

Comment: This perfectly solved my problem,thank you

Comment: @radrow, I have the same issue using macOs 12.0.1, but adding that line to ```package.yaml``` doesn't solve the issue unfortunately. Is there anything that I could to to resolve that?

Comment: Are you adding this line to the right place? it might be in the `library` section, but also `executable` depending on your setup

Comment: @radrow, I added it to the ```library``` section... There is the same problem even if I load some external package, like ```timeit``` and try to install it (when I run ```runhaskell Setup.hs configure```). Is there a way to reinstall something?

Comment: I think you should ask it as a separate question and show your case in more details